# My Professor isn't submitting my reference letter

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter

On September 1st, I asked my professors to write LORs for a grad program I'm applying to and told them the deadline is October 12th. It's actually a rolling admission, but I said October 12th to get it in ASAP. My application isn't considered complete until they get all components of the application. Both agreed. I sent follow up emails: One on October 5th and one on October 12th as reminders. One professor submitted it and emailed me to let me know. The other still hasn't submitted it, so I sent him another letter today and he hasn't replied. He usually replies ASAP.

My friend once got a LOR from him and she told me he submitted her letter like a month late.

I'm really stressed out. I'm not on campus this semester so I can't talk to him in person. What else can I do?

Comment: Can you call them by phone?

Comment: I support Paul's answer having been in a similar situation [myself](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/85767/how-long-should-one-wait-for-a-reference-before-writing-to-the-course-convenor). Give them a call.

Comment: I assume they have explicitly agreed to send a LOR, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My sympathies. Some people are ... to put it politely... procrastinators. The bad effects this can have on other people make me think to give such people a more judgemental label, but I'll not do it right now.

As a comment suggests: call them on the phone... send another email... and be prepared to ask someone else to write the letter.